# How to configure my ECore model to have a cross-document ereference during XMI serialization?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, emf

In my ECore model, I have two EClass : `User` and `Application`. Users can belong to several applications and applications can hold several users. To achieve that, I put an EReference called "users" in the Application EClass and each user has its own XMI file after XMI serialization.

However during XMI serialization of application I get something like :

```
<MyScheme:Application xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:MyScheme="http://my.company.model/3.0" users="ID1 ID2">
...
</MyScheme:Application>
```

Whereas I would like to have a cross-document reference such as :

```
<MyScheme:Application xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:MyScheme="http://my.company.model/3.0">
...
<users href="..." />
<users href="..." />

</MyScheme:Application>
```

How do I have to configure my ECore model to get that ?

EDIT : User has no eContainer

Comment: I think that the `EReference users` should be set as an `eContainment` if you want the reference written in this way. However, you will lost the "Users can belong to several application" constraint though.

Comment: When you say "the <code>EReference</code> users should be set as an <code>eContainment</code>, you mean set the <code>Containement</code> property of my <code>EReference</code> to <code>true</code> ?

Comment: Yep. But if you do that, you will not be able to link a `User` to one or more of  `Application` through the `users` ref :\. Why do you need the XMI models to be in different files?

Comment: I already tried that : user data have been copied into my application XMI file which is quite ugly isn't it ?

Comment: We need to save model of users in separate files because of the many to many relationship : we can reuse user information in different applications

Comment: A solution could be to create a `UserReference` like this: https://repository.genmymodel.com/vincent.aranega/ApplicationsMM. This way, you can load a `User` instance in a `Resource`, the `Application` in another one and have this containment relationship and still be able to reference `User` instances in many `Application`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this proposal ! I'm going to try this and go back to you. Thank you again !

Comment: Unfortunately, your proposal ends with the same issue... But I finally found a solution : I've shared it: see answer to this question

Comment: Strange, it works fine on my tests (this is the same kind of solution that is used by UML for `PackageImport`). Anyway, I'm glad you found what you need :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't got the expected result because my "User" do not have any eResource attached (so it was not a container/containment issue). To fix it, I simply did that :

```
AdapterFactoryEditingDomain editingDomain = // ...
Resource r = editingDomain.createResource(uri);
r.getContents().add(user)
```

Hoping that solution will help someone !